# Web Speech API SpeechRecognition not defined when using React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

I am using React.js along with the Web Speech API's SpeechRecognition, however, it does not work and I get the error "ReferenceError: SpeechRecognition is not defined." The code I am using is directly from the SpeechRecognition documentation:

```
const SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
```

The first line causes the error, but without it, the second line will cause the same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10):

try `window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;`

See [Using the Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API#javascript) for further explanation why you need the `window.` prefix.

Comment: Your answer is correct, but it will be more helpful if you add explanation.

Comment: It's not yet standardize and supported in Firefox. Therefore the prefix

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

Instead of

```
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
```

Write:

```
const recognition = new speechRecognition();
```

This helped me!